# How do I start a career race?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, f1-2011

I'm playing Formula 1 2011 for the 3DS and I can't for the life of me figure out how to actually start my racing career.

I went to the Career menu, then opened the Laptop and accepted two trial invitations. They show up on my calendar, but I don't see any way to actually go and race.

How do I start one of those trials?